# Express.js: app.param(param, callback) not fired for ?param=

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to use the Express app.param() feature like this:

```
app.route('/blueprints/:subject?/:date?/:lang?')
  .get(blueprints.query);

app.param('subject', blueprints.filterBySubject);
app.param('date', blueprints.filterByDate);
app.param('lang', blueprints.filterByLang);
```

It works for `/blueprints/abc/2014-02-02/en` but doesn't fire when using `/blueprints?subject=abc&date=2014-02-02&lang=en`. Am I doing something wrong, is that a bug or just the way it's supposed to work?

Answer (score 0):

remove the question marks ...

```
app.route('/blueprints/:subject/:date/:lang')
```

and (just for better style) I favour to put app.param on top.